# htaccess rewrite when query string is empty does not works

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make a 302 redirect from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/root/` avoiding the redirection of `mysite.com/?s=hello` to `mysite.com/root/?s=hello`.

Currently I am using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Home
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RedirectMatch ^/$ /root/

# WordPress Redirect
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is not working because is redirecting in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` is doesn't go with `RewriteCond`. It should be `RewriteRule` and regex pattern also needs to be fixed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Home
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /root/ [L,R=302]

# WordPress Redirect
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note use of `R=302` in first rule to get `302` status.